# CSS: How to produce rounded boxed list

Tags: css

I would like to reproduce the following in the simplest way (probably using a `<ul>`):
[image]

So, I would like to be able to add as many rows as I want to this list, each row being composed of a picture, a description and a counter.
The list should be in a rounded box, and the rows should be separated with lines.

Could someone with CSS skills help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anything that you have tried already?

Comment: Not really! I'm looking at CSS documentation but I figured I might end up using a nasty and complicated way, whereas someone could have a nice (reusable) solution for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [here's one way of doing it](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/pY5MP/1/).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/16/16">
        Item 1
        <span>1</span>
    </li>

    <!-- More list items -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Container with border and rounded corners */
ul {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;

    /* Border radius for Chrome, Webkit and other good browsers */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Only add border to bottom of <li> */
li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* Get rid of the last <li>'s bottom border to stop overlap with <ul>'s border */
/* :last-child works in IE7+ */
li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Get the number and float it right */
span {
    float: right;
}
​
```

Comment: I would copy the image to css and use it there as a background-image per ID (or possibly via "nth-child").

Comment: @BramVanroy Of course. I was using `<img src="http://placekitten.com/16/16>` just as an example. In the actual implementation, one could use whatever they like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H245D/) for you.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://ghickman.co.uk/images/sidebar/stackoverflow.png"/> <span>text</span> <span class="num">1</span></li>
   <li><img src="http://ghickman.co.uk/images/sidebar/stackoverflow.png"/> <span>text</span> <span class="num">1</span></li>
   <li><img src="http://ghickman.co.uk/images/sidebar/stackoverflow.png"/> <span>text</span> <span class="num">1</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
    margin:10px;
    width:200px;
}

li:last-child {
    padding:7px;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
    padding:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;
}

span.num {
    float:right;
}
img {
    width:20px;
}

span {
    float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you even tried to google for "rounded corners" but anyway, you have 2 options:

1. using CSS property [border radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/), but note it will not work in IE7
2. use image and `background` property

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>Event</li>
   <li>Journal</li>
   <li>Task</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; background:#3d3d3; border:1px solid gray; width:400px; }
ul li { padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px; border-top:1px solid gray; }
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v7J8/2/) for that.